# How do I use CSS grid to get items to span multiple grid columns based on their native width?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid, responsive

I'm displaying a list of items in a css grid with a maximum number of columns. The items' content varies in size, and if it doesn't fit into one column, I want the items to span multiple ones, up to the number in the entire grid.

Googling gave me [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/an-auto-filling-css-grid-with-max-columns/), which looked similar though not quite what I was looking for, but close enough to start there and make adjustments. The result was below:

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #111;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-results-list {
  list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    --grid-column-count: 4;
    --grid-item--min-width: 320px;
    --grid-layout-gap: 10px;
    
    --gap-count: calc(var(--grid-column-count) - 1);
    --total-gap-width: calc(var(--gap-count) * var(--grid-layout-gap));
    --grid-item--max-width: calc((100% - var(--total-gap-width))/ var(--grid-column-count));
  
  --grid-actual-columns: min(round(down, calc(100% / var(--grid-item--min-width))), var(--grid-column-count));
    
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(max(var(--grid-item--min-width), var(--grid-item--max-width)), 1fr));
    grid-gap: var(--grid-layout-gap);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.search-results-list li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-results-card {
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background: #E0F2F1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 0 5px;
    
  grid-column: span round(down, calc(max-content / calc(100% / var(--grid-actual-columns))));
}

.desired {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.col-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background: lime;
}

.col-3 {
  background: tomato;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="search-results-list">
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Medium Length</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">A Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Another Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Even Longer Than Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">A Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Another Short</li>
</ul>

<ul class="search-results-list desired">
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Medium Length</li>
  <li class="search-results-card col-2">Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card col-2">Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">A Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Another Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card col-3">Even Longer Than Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">A Short</li>
  <li class="search-results-card">Another Short</li>
</ul>
```

How would I get top list (black background) to appear like the bottom list (cyan background), but without pre-assigning css classes to specific items to be used when setting `grid-column: span` value -- I need to make that assignment solely based on item content, and I need to do it with HTML and CSS only (no JavaScript).

Is this even possible? I discovered several problems in the course of experimentation with this setup:

- The item within the grid doesn't know the number of grid columns, and can't calculate them, since the CSS calculation that determines that (the `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(max(var(--grid-item--min-width), var(--grid-item--max-width)), 1fr));` line) isn't by itself a number and is useless outside the `grid-template-columns` directive.
- `grid-column: span round(%SOMEVALUE%);` is an invalid directive -- even though round should produce an integer, this statement always assigns 1 column to the item in question, regardless of what %SOMEVALUE% is

So, how do I go about doing this sort of dynamic column number assignment?

Comment: You overcomplicate the issue instead of using the `gap` property. Unlike Flexbox, CSS-Grid element's width will subtract the gaps by default!

Comment: I think that’s to determine when to adjust the column number. In the above example, in a window exactly 960px wide, that’ll fit 3 minimum width columns of 320px — but not with gaps, so we should drop to 2. The problem I’m having is setting the `grid-column: span` correctly on the grid item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using float:left instead of grid for this? It seems like you want to add random items and have them fall in as they may without changing the natural width of the element. Short of possibly rounding each of their widths to the nearest nth column width, if you want them to fall in as they may then I would suggest floating them. I've got good results floating every other one right and every other one left. makes resizing look cool. just a thought.

Comment: That will mean each item is displayed at its own natural width, while I want item width to come in multiples of the same value -- which is done by allowing items to occupy multiple columns in the grid. It's doable as the example shows, when you know which items will be big in advance, but I need it to work when I don't.